# TypeError: undefined is not a function in $location.$$state angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am trying to add data to $location.$$state object, currently doing console.log($location.$$state) gives me

```
Object
key: "Core/Views/dash:1"
parameters: Array[0]
view: "Core/Views/dash"
```

I want to add below data to state object

```
breadcrumb : Array[4]
```

I tried below code but gives me error

```
$location.$$state.push({breadcrumb:['home','page1','page2,'page3']});
```

Error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Any idea how can I add property to an existing state object?

Comment: You can't add an element to an object using `push`, this is for Arrays. If I understand what you want to do correctly, you should just write: `$location.$$state.breadcrumb = ['home', 'page1', 'page2', 'page3'];`.

Comment: yea correct, my bad ...was thinking to use Object.defineProperty() but your solution works as well thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `'` (single quote) to your code will solve the issue.

```
$location.$$state.push({breadcrumb:['home','page1','page2','page3']});
```